# Изменение ссылок во всех файлах проекта в VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Имеется проект/сайт, написанный на php. Изменилась структура проекта: добавилась папочка с материалом, и туда был перенесён весь материал.
Как быстро изменить ссылки во всех файлах страниц на этот материал?

Задавал вопрос ИИ боту, выдал Linker, но его я не нашёл в расширениях VS Code
Использовать переменные в php не хочется.

Подскажите расширение, или программку для моих хотелок. Спасибо!

Comment: нефеншуйный sed противопоказан?

Comment: Не шарю за sed. Проект без заказчика, просто тренировка, грубо говоря :)